# Integrating Dropbox chooser in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api, url-scheme

In my iOS app i am trying to fetch details of a file stored in dropbox on click of button.
I am trying to choose a file from dropbox and redirect back to my application using DBChooser. It works fine when a user is already logged in the Dropbox.

```
 -(void)choose{
  [[DBChooser defaultChooser] openChooserForLinkType:DBChooserLinkTypeDirect fromViewController:self
                                        completion:^(NSArray *results)
 {
     if ([results count]) {
         _result = results[0];
         link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _result.link];
         name = _result.name;
         size = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld", _result.size];
         icon = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _result.iconURL];
     } else {
         _result = nil;
         [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"CANCELLED" message:@"user cancelled!"
                                    delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil]
          show];
     }
 }];
}
```

Also i have following function in Appdelegate.m

```
   -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:   
  (NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
   {
    if ([[DBChooser defaultChooser] handleOpenURL:url]) {
    // This was a Chooser response and handleOpenURL automatically ran the
    // completion block
     return YES;
    }
     return NO;
   }
```

Problem starts when user is not logged in and when i click on button it opens dropbox and asks me to enter credentials. After successful logged in, i am able to view my dropbox data, but i am not able to choose anything i.e. on clicking an image it should redirect me back to my aplication, instead it is opening that image in dropbox itself. This happens only when user is not logged in.
  I have set the URL schemes for the DropIns used for chooser. I just need to verify if user is logged in the dropbox before calling the choose function. Please help i am stuck on this.

Comment: What version of the Dropbox iOS app are you using? Also, what device and what iOS version have you seen this with?

Comment: I am using DBChooser sdk v 1.1 from the following link https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/ios , Also i am currently developing it both for iOS6, iOS7 and iPhone, iPad

Comment: What version of the Dropbox for iOS app itself are you using? (Latest is currently 3.0.2 https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dropbox/id327630330?mt=8 )

Comment: Hi greg, just wanted to update that the above mentioned issue is resolved in the latest dropbox v 3.0.3 and dropbox chooser sdk version 1.2.1, thanks for your support greg.